How do I make the text bold and have space in between in tkinter python?

In my code, I only want to make the sender name bold. This means I only want to make "User" and "Gpt-3.5-turbo" bold. For some reason, messages sent by "User" is always bold. Additionally, there is no new line between "User" and "Gpt-3.5-turbo" as seen in the image I've attached, although there is space in between the very first message by "User" and "Gpt-3.5-turbo". I've tried many commands to fix this issue but no luck. Can someone help me out in fixing these 2 issues? Below is my code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime
import openai
import json
import requests

history = []

# Create a function to use ChatGPT 3.5 turbo to answer a question based on the prompt
def get_answer_from_chatgpt(prompt, history):
    openai.api_key = "sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    print("Trying")

    messages = [
            {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."}
        ]

    for sender, message in history:
            messages.append({"role": sender, "content": message})

    try:
        stream = openai.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=messages,
            stream=True,
            
        )
        append_to_chat_log("Gpt-3.5-turbo")
        for chunk in stream:
            if chunk.choices[0].delta.content is not None:
               chunk = chunk.choices[0].delta.content
               append_to_chat_log(message=chunk) 
               #history.append(("assistant", chunk))
        append_to_chat_log(message="\n")
        
        #chat_log.insert("end",'\n\n')
        
        print("Streamig complete")        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request."


def append_to_chat_log(sender=None, message=None):
   
    chat_log.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
    if sender:
        chat_log.insert("end", f"{sender}\n\n", "sender")
        
        #chat_log.insert("end",'\n\n')
    if message:
        chat_log.insert("end", message)
    chat_log.tag_config("sender", font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'))
    chat_log.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    chat_log.see("end")
    chat_log.update()


def send_message(event=None):
    global history
    message = message_entry.get(1.0, "end-1c") 
    message = message.strip()
    message_entry.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    message_entry.update()
    
    if not message:
        pass 
    else:
        append_to_chat_log("User")
        append_to_chat_log(message)
        history.append(("user", message))
        if len(history) >4:
            history = history[-4:]

        get_answer_from_chatgpt(message, history)
        print(history)

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Chat")

# Maximize the window
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)

chat_frame = tk.Frame(root)
chat_frame.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

chat_log = tk.Text(chat_frame, state='disabled', wrap='word', width=70, height=30, font=('Arial', 12), highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
chat_log.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(500,0), pady=10)


message_entry = tk.Text(root, padx=17, insertbackground='white', width=70, height=1, spacing1=20, spacing3=20, font=('Open Sans', 14))
message_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(500, 0), pady=(0, 70))  # Adjust pady to move it slightly above the bottom
#message_entry.insert(0, "Ask me anything...")
message_entry.insert(1.0, "Ask me anything...")
message_entry.mark_set("insert", "%d.%d" % (0,0))
message_entry.bind("<Return>", send_message)
#message_entry.bind("<Button-1>", click)

root.mainloop()

I've tried using commands like chat_log.insert("end",'\n\n') and append_to_chat_log(message="\n") in def get_answer_from_chatgpt(prompt, history): function but none seem to work.

tkinter uses tags which you have to assign to appended text - and later you can assign different styles (bold, color, etc) to different tags. I think this problem was few times on Stackoveflow.

python - Tagging in a text widget - tkinter - Stack Overflow

maybe your original text already has new lines and you have to remove them with text = text.strip()

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

The message from user is bold because you call append_to_chat_log() wrong on message and you need to use message option as below:
def send_message(event=None):
    ...
    else:
        append_to_chat_log("User")  # log the sender
        append_to_chat_log(message=message)  # log the message
        ...

To add newlines between messages, you can add newlines messages before and after GPT response:
def get_answer_from_chatgpt(message, history):
    ...
    try:
        ...
        # add newlines before response
        append_to_chat_log(message="\n\n")
        append_to_chat_log("Gpt-3.5-turbo")
        for chunk in stream:
            ...
        # add newlines after response
        append_to_chat_log(message="\n\n")
        ...
    ...

